# VB.Net IEquatable, Access Denied

Tags: vb.net, interface, access-denied, iequatable

I just have a simple Interface definition in my project, which I haven't even used yet. But when I try to build the project I get this error:

Access is denied: 'System.IEquatable`1[Reactor.IOptions]'.

Below is the interface:

```
    Interface IOptions
            Inherits Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable             ' Optoins Should Serialize to XML
            Inherits System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable     ' Options should implement .net Serialization
            Inherits System.ICloneable                              ' Must be able to copy options
            Inherits System.IEquatable(Of IOptions)                 ' Must be able to compare opitons
    End Interface
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what happend but after changing a bunch of stuff and then chaning it back to the way it was the error resoveled itself. Must have just been a Visual Studio hiccup.